# getChildHtml on category view

Tags: category, attributes, product-attribute, product-list

I want to load getChildHtml on category view.
 I just tried this:

Inside list.phtml I added this line:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('specificaties'); ?>
```

In local.xml I added this line inside 
`<catalog_category_layered> 
<reference name="content">` :

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="specificaties" as="specificaties" template="catalog/product/list/specificaties.phtml"/>
```

And inside the specificaties.phtml I added this code:

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
    $helperSnippets = $this->helper('ultimo/rsnippets');
?>

<?php $yourCatIds = array(235);
$productCats = $_product->getAvailableInCategories();

if (count(array_intersect($yourCatIds,$productCats))) {
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_display_diagonal_944_1') . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_processor_family_2196_1') . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="test even">' . $_product->getAttributeText('i_internal_memory_11381_1') . '</li>';
}
?>
```

But that breaks down the page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Covering basics: what's the layout handle that `<reference name="content">` is in? And are you using flat category and if so, are those attributes set to "use in product listing"?

Comment: It is handeling the layout <catalog_category_default>. And we are using category with layered navigation. Yes, attribute set is set to "use in product listing". But the problem is that the external .phtml file is not loaded.

Comment: With flat category I mean: `System > Configuration > [Catalog:Catalog] > Frontend`: Use Flat Catalog Category

Comment: Whoops sorry, yes we use flat category! (for speed optimisation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attributes are most likely not set to "Use in product listing". This means there are no columns named `i_display_diagonal_944_1` and so on in the table `catalog_category_flat_store_X` where X is the store id of the store view. In addition it's very likely that they are not in the result of the collection.

First you have to mark each attribute as "used in product listen" via manage attributes in the backend:

[image: Use in product listing]

Then specifically for flat catalog, you have to write an observer that adds them to the result set:

Event: catalog_category_flat_loadnodes_before
Method details:

```
public function onCatalogCategoryFlatLoadnodesBefore($observer)
{
    $extra = array('my_attribute', 'my_other_attribute');
    $observer->getSelect()->columns($extra);
}
```

Edit (above is not the problem at all):

Your block isn't a product list: it doesn't handle the product collection, it handles one item of it. So `$this->getProduct()` doesn't give you anything, since `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` has no method getProduct() nor a product attribute. Look into this piece of code (in a Magento 1.9.1 rwd template) that has hooks for things you want shown after the standard details:

```
                    <?php
                    // Provides extra blocks on which to hang some features for products in the list
                    // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                    if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                            $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                            $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                            echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```

So it's probably easiest to hook in there and the important part is that the product is passed on to the template. The same applies to for example `<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>`, where again the product is passed onto the template.

Edit 2:
If you choose to split it out and use the parent's variable names, then change the type to `core/template`, as it doesn't need the `catalog/product_list` block information:

```
<block type="core/template" name="specificaties" template="catalog/product/list/specificaties.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Melvyn! When I place the code directly into the list.phtml the code works fine. But loading the code with an external .phtml file, by adding it to the local.xml file, that does brake the page. So I need to know what I need to add to our local.xml file, to load the external .phtml file correctly

Comment: Ah, I see! For future reference, saying "it works in list.phtml, but not as external phtml" is useful information :)

Comment: I added my question! But do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but my code does work directly into the list.phtml, but do I need to edit this? I really do not understand how to fix this problem. Especially not with loading the code inside and external .phtml file

Comment: Your code is different, because you're redefining `$_product` as `$this->getProduct()`. You either write a template that can be included in different pages and so you need to pass it the information it needs **or** you know that [php include](http://php.net/include) allows you to use variables from the calling template and use the same names. If you choose the second path, there's really no good reason to split it out into a separate template and only drawbacks (variable name changes in the parent, have to be kept in sync with the child).

Comment: What do you think is the best solution to do? What I want is to display the 3 most important attributes of the product, below the product name in the category view. And the 3 most important attributes are different for each category. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: That depends on what you're comfortable with. Passing data to the template allows you to use it for other product-list-type blocks, like up- and cross-sell. But...you then have to figure out how to pass the names of the 3 attributes to the template (can be done using helpers). So overall, it's much easier to keep this code inline and not use a separate template at all. Either way, I can highly recommend [this book](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout) to help you with your decision making.

Comment: Thanks for you reply again! But I really do not know how to manage all these attributes. Because the code needs to check if the product is inside some category and then display only attributes that are important for that product. Can you help me with this problem outside the forum?